# Two VirtualHost websites do not work together under Apache 2.4

Tags: apache2, dns, webserver, hosts, apache2.4

I'm running Apache 2.4 under Ubuntu 18.04

I'm having this problem where all addresses I type onto the browser bar get redirected to **one** of the two websites I have configured (in this case, whenever I type an address that should redirect to `other-site`, I get shown the website under `jekyll` only.)

For example:

- typing `jekyll` on the browser shows me the jekyll website, as expected
- typing `other-site` on the browser **also shows me the jekyll website**, even though there is another VirtualHost listening on that name

I have these **two separate sites** configured as VHosts under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (both of them **enabled** via `a2ensite`)

- **jekyll.conf**

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/jekyll/_site
        LimitRequestFieldSize 48000
         <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/jekyll/_site>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/jekyll/_site/>
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ServerName jekyll
        ServerName http://jekyll
        ServerName http://localhost/jekyll

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- **other-site.conf**

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/other-site/_site
        LimitRequestFieldSize 48000
         <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/other-site/_site>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/other-site/_site/>
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ServerName other-site
        ServerName http://other-site
        ServerName http://localhost/other-site

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

I have also added these entries to `/etc/hosts` so that localhost gets redirected to each site:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost/jekyll
127.0.0.1       localhost/other-site
127.0.0.1       jekyll
127.0.0.1       other-site
127.0.1.1       felipe-Inspiron-7559
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ServerName` attribute in your Apache configuration files needn't be repeated, as each subsequent line will replace the previous ones.

Instead, you can use `ServerName` with `ServerAlias` like this:

```
ServerName jekyll
ServerAlias jekyll.local *.jekyll *.jekyll.local
```

Note that this is illogical:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost/jekyll
127.0.0.1       localhost/other-site
```

These are not domains (or subdomains), but paths under `localhost`. As a result, only `localhost` will be observed. This is why I did not include it in the Apache config as noted above.

So, with this in mind, you can have *three* Apache configuration files:

⇢ `000-jekyll.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      ServerName jekyll
      ServerAlias jekyll.local *.jekyll *.jekyll.local

      DirectoryIndex index.html
      DocumentRoot /var/www/jekyll/_site
      LimitRequestFieldSize 48000

      <Directory /var/www/jekyll/_site>
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jekyll-error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jekyll-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

⇢ `001-other.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      ServerName other-site
      ServerAlias other-site.local *.other-site *.other-site.local

      DirectoryIndex index.html
      DocumentRoot /var/www/other-site/_site
      LimitRequestFieldSize 48000

      <Directory /var/www/other-site/_site>
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other-error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

⇢ `999-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      ServerName localhost
      ServerAlias *.localhost * *.*

      DirectoryIndex index.html
      DocumentRoot /var/www
      LimitRequestFieldSize 48000

      <Directory /var/www>
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/local-error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/local-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache processes traffic based on the order of the configuration files. So any domain matching the ones specified in `000-jekyll.conf` will be handled by that file. If no matches are found, then `001-other.conf` will be checked. If no matches are found, then `999-default.conf` will be used. Note the `ServerAlias` in the `999-default.conf` file and how it's relying on wide-open wildcards. This means that it will be treated as a catch-all for the traffic that does not match defined config files.

<sup>**Note:** The Apache configuration files were streamlined to eliminate irrelevant `Directory` blocks and to have each host use their own error logs.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, i was really messing up the `ServerName` directives there. Thanks!